# Sobre CSS flexbox: valores iguais para propriedades diferentes do CSS

Tags: html5, css3

Estou estudando as documentações da linguagem, e me ocorreu a seguinte dúvida:

Tanto a propriedade `align-content` quanto a propriedade `align-items` aceita os valores:

- `flex-start`
- `flex-end`
- `stretch`

E vendo os exemplos, não consegui ver diferença.

Então qual seria a diferença entre as duas propriedades?

Como saber, por exemplo, quando escrever `flex-start` em `align-content` ou `align-items`?

Answer (score 3):

Ambos são destinados a manipular o conteúdo de um elemento que seja `display: flex;`, este chamaremos de elemento pai.

O `align-items` é mais usual, pois ele é independente da quantidade de linhas que os filhos do elemento pai possuem.

Diferente do `align-content` que apenas há efeito quando os filhos do elemento pai, ocupam mais de uma linha.

Aqui um excelente  [guia de flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), que explica melhor oque foi dito acima.

Answer (score 3):

O `align-content` só tem efeito em conjunto com a propriedade `flex-wrap` com o valor `wrap` e se houver quebra de linha.

Por exemplo, se tiver um contêiner de `100px` flex com duas divs filhas que não cabem na largura, haverá uma quebra de linha obrigatória. Logo, o `align-content` irá definir a posição das divs filhas.

Exemplo de duas divs filhas, uma com `80px` e outra com `30px`. Logo, 80px + 30px = 120px, é maior que a largura do contêiner, e isso irá forçar a quebra de linha com `flex-wrap: wrap`, e o `align-content` irá definir o alinhamento das divs. No exemplo abaixo, no centro do contêiner:

```css
.it{
   display: flex;
   align-content: center;
   width: 100px;
   height: 200px;
   background: red;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.it div{
  background: blue;
}

#f1{
   width: 80px;
   height: 30px;
}

#f2{
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="it">
   <div id="f1">div1</div>
   <div id="f2">div2</div>
</div>
```

Se não houver quebra de linha, ou seja, se as duas divs filhas forem igual ou menor que a largura do contêiner, não haverá quebra de linha, logo a propriedade `align-content` não terá nenhum efeito:

```css
.it{
   display: flex;
   align-content: flex-end;
   width: 100px;
   height: 200px;
   background: red;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.it div {
  background: blue;
}

#f1{
   width: 80px;
   height: 30px;
}

#f2{
   width: 20px;
   height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="it">
   <div id="f1">div1</div>
   <div id="f2">div2</div>
</div>
```

Já a propriedade `align-items` irá alinhar todas as divs filhas independente de quebra de linha ou não. Se houver quebra de linha, irá alinhar as divs de forma igual no contêiner:

```css
.it{
   display: flex;
   align-items: flex-start;
   width: 100px;
   height: 200px;
   background: red;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.it div {
  background: blue;
}

#f1{
   width: 80px;
   height: 30px;
}

#f2{
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="it">
   <div id="f1">div1</div>
   <div id="f2">div2</div>
</div>
```

Se não houver quebra de linha, da mesma forma:

```css
.it{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   width: 100px;
   height: 200px;
   background: red;
}

.it div {
  background: blue;
}

#f1{
   width: 80px;
   height: 30px;
}

#f2{
   width: 20px;
   height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="it">
   <div id="f1">div1</div>
   <div id="f2">div2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Boa explicação Tio, só uma obs. é que para funcionar o container flex pai precisa tb de ter uma altura definida, sem um height no pai ele sempre vai ter a altura dos filhos, e os alinhamentos não serão aplicados pq não tem altura "sobrando" para alinha-los dentro do container pai...

Comment: Exatamente tio. Cara, pra falar a verdade, tem muita coisa pra explicar nessas propriedades... eu que tentei ser mais curto possível mesmo :D

Comment: Mas a outra resposta foi boa tb, bem sintética, mas boa.